# paintComponent and java Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm still new to java graphics, I wrote this little piece of code, but it doesn't show anything on the screen. can someone please tell me what's wrong.
I'm not getting any errors, but it just doesn't show anything. Thanks

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.*;


public class GraphicsExample extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponenet(Graphics g) {


        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; 
        g.setColor(Color.red);

        g.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
        g.setColor(new Color((int) (Math.random() *255), (int)(Math.random()*255),(int) (Math.random()*255)));
        g.fillOval(20+(int)(Math.random()*180), 20+(int)(Math.random()*180), 5, 5);
    }
        g.setColor(Color.red);

        g.drawString("Hello there", 20, 20);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame(); 
        f.add(new GraphicsExample());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400,600);
        f.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in `paintComponent` name (in your code it's `paintComponenet`). Use `@Override` notation to get rid of such errors.

Comment: Yeah, when I run it it doesn't show anything

Comment: Oh I see! didn't notice that! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paintComponenet` is missed spelt, it should be `paintComponent`

Start by using the `@Override` annotation when you "think" you're overriding methods...

```
@Override
public void paintComponenet(Graphics g) {
```

This will cause a compiler error if the compiler can't find a corresponding method in the parent classes, which will highlight these types of errors...

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

Comment: just one clarification needed , when this `paintComponent()` will get called ?

Comment: It will be called by the system when it decides that the component needs to be repainted for some reason.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details